# Move folder structure from one computer to another computer when these computers aren't networked?

Tags: vb.net, vba, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have two computers that aren't networked. I need to replicate the folder structure of one drive that exists on one computer and put it on the other computer. Both Windows 7 machines. I don't need the files, just folders/directories. The drive letters are the same on both computers (Y). The computers are miles apart physically, but I do have access to the computer I am trying to get the folder structure of via LogMeIn.

I am thinking I need to save the folder structure to a file using some process. Move that file to my computer (via email or LogMeIn File Manager) and run some process to put in on my computer.

Is there a better solution? If not, is there code out there to do this via VBA, Cmd window, .bat script, VB.NET, or VBS? I know I can write it in VBA, but I'd rather not recreate the wheel if I don't have to.

I don't have a 'process'/program that does this. LogMeIn File Manager doesn't do this either (I asked). There are lots of paths on this drive that I need so creating them by hand would take a long time. I searched and found a lot of solutions that work with computers that are networked, but these computers are not networked, hence why I think I need to save it to a file. Again, I don't want all the files on the drive (its huge and most of the files are unnecessary), just folders.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory listing of the source computer and redirect the output to a text file:

```
dir /ad /b /s >> dirlist.txt
```

The switches to `dir` are (more info at [MS TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx)):

```
/ad     List only files with attribute of directory
/b      Bare format (no heading information or summary)
/s      Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories
```

Transfer `dirlist.txt` from the source computer to the destination computer.

On the destination computer, use a `for /F` with that text file from the command prompt to create the directory structure:

```
for /F "delims=" %i in (dirlist.txt) do md "%i"
```

The switches to `for` are documented at [MS TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx)

Comment: The above seems to work except when there is a space in one of the directory names. I'm currently looking up ways to wrap the paths in quotes so this doesn't happen.

Comment: See my edited answer. It correctly handles directories with spaces that it reads from the text file.

Comment: For the extreme newbie, you can run these two lines in the cmd window. Thanks for the edit Ken. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: This is quite impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. Windows command `xcopy source destination /T /E`.  The `/T` option creates the directory structure, and the `/E` option includes empty directories.
2. Bundle the empty directory structure into an installer (perhaps as a zip file).
3. If the structure isn't relatively small and not likely to change, you could just put a bunch of `md` commands into a batch file.
4. Combination - `xcopy` the structure locally, zip it, transfer it, unzip it.